# Better way to calculate λ in a Poisson distribution if the probability of occurrence P(X>0) is known

Tags: python, poisson

Currently I am using the following function but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way or a simple formula to accomplish this?

```
from scipy.stats import poisson

def calc_expected_value(event_proba):
    x = 0.01
    while round(1 - poisson.pmf(0, x), 2) != round(event_proba, 2):
        x += 0.01
    return x
```

Comment: Please define your use of the phrase "probability of occurrence".  Do you mean P{X=1}?

Comment: Actually I mean P{X>0}. I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`P(X = 0) = exp(-lambda)`, hence `P(X > 0) = 1 - exp(-lambda)`. If you call this probability `event_proba`, then

```
exp(-lambda) = 1 - event_proba
```

hence

```
lambda = -log(1 - event_proba)
```

Of course, in actual Python code you should avoid the name `lambda` since it has a built-in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is as a simple formula:

```python
from math import log

def calc_lambda(p_gt_0):
    return -log(1.0 - p_gt_0)
```

This is derived from the fact that P{X=0} = 1 - P{X>0}.
Plug in the formula for a Poisson probability and solve to yield the implementation given above.

Comment: Perfect, what if I P(X=any number) is known though? Sorry for not including this in my question , it just occured to me that I might need it.

Comment: @sierra_papa For the Poisson, `P{X=x} = lambda^x * exp(-lambda) / x!`.  When `x=0` we have that both `lambda^x` and `x!` are 1, so it reduces to just the single exponential term and yields the closed-form solution John Coleman & I came up with.  Things don't break as cleanly for any case other than `P{X=0}`, and you're left with `lambda` as both a base and a power. For example, when `x=1` you have to solve `lambda * exp(-lambda) = p`. At that point I think you're stuck with solving it numerically with root finding algorithms.